# How to properly set up multiple sites with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm currently setting up a new site on an existing server. Currently I have a file for both sites `old-site.com` and `new-site.com` along with the `default` in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory. Each of the folders have been symlinked in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory.

The issue I'm continuing to get is that when trying to go to `new-site.com` I'm redirected to `old-site.com`. I've tried also just simply adding a new block to the `old-site.com`'s file but that only caused to domain name to be attached to the wrong site..

This is on an Ubuntu Server (16.04.1) running NGINX.

### `/etc/nginx/sites-available/old-site.com`

```
  root /var/www/html/old-site.com/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name old-site.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 168h;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/old-site.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/old-site.com-0001/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;\
}

server {
        server_name www.old-site.com;
        return 301 $scheme://old-site.com$request_uri;

    listen 80; 

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.old-site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.old-site.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

### `/etc/nginx/sites-available/new-site.com`

Is the same as above with `new-site.com`

### `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Is same as `old-site.com`

The expected outcome is to go to the separate domain name and see their corresponding sites.

---

### UPDATE

I got the `new-site` to stop redirecting by removing the https block as it wasn't currently set up and was throwing an error on the server, but it now just serves the `old-site`.

Comment: is `new-site` file linked to `sites-enabled`? You should not have 2 files with the same server names i.e. default and old-site as one will never be use and might cause issues.

Comment: Yes `new-site` file is linked.

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed the Issue

The issue related to a bug within a redirect. `new-site.com` and `old-site.com` are now showing their respective sites.